# How to overlay two seaborn relplots?

Tags: python, plot, seaborn

I have two data sets (consider the following MWE), from which I want to create relplots with different style parameters.

```
from io import StringIO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data1 = """index   x   y   group    ground_x_A    ground_y_A     ground_x_B    ground_y_B
0    27    26  A   20  15   40  45
1    26    27  A   20  15   40  45
2    28    22  A   20  15   40  45
3    25    24  A   20  15   40  45
4    29    31  A   20  15   40  45
5    46    29  B   20  15   40  45
6    39    37  B   20  15   40  45
7    38    41  B   20  15   40  45
8    44    46  B   20  15   40  45
9    46    38  B   20  15   40  45
10   37    33  B   20  15   40  45"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), index_col=[0], sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True)

sns.set_style("whitegrid")

sns.relplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'group', s = 25)
sns.relplot(data = df, x = 'ground_x_A', y = 'ground_y_B', s = 100)
sns.relplot(data = df, x = 'ground_x_B', y = 'ground_y_B', s = 100)
```

I would like to overlay the generated plots (i.e. combining them into one single plot), with the dots from plot 2 & 3 matching the colors for each group from plot 1. Can someone point me into the right direction?

(I have unsuccessfully tried to adapt the solution introduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034473/how-to-combine-two-relplots-in-seaborn-python) to my example.)

Comment: For second relplot, did you mean to compare `x_A` with `y_A` and mistyped latter for `y_B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`relplot` creates a new figure (a `FacetGrid`) at each call, so you cannot use that. That being said, `relplot()` uses `scatterplot()` to do the actual plotting.

```
palette={'A':'C3', 'B':'C4'}

sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'group', s = 25, palette=palette)
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = 'ground_x_A', y = 'ground_y_B', s = 100, color=palette['A'])
sns.scatterplot(data = df, x = 'ground_x_B', y = 'ground_y_B', s = 100, color=palette['B'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Consider restructuring data into long format with `concat` for a single `relplot` where you incorporate two rows for new `group` values for `hue` factoring.

```
main_df = df.loc[:, ['x', 'y', 'group']]

ground_A_df = (df.loc[:, ['ground_x_A', 'ground_y_A']]
                 .assign(group = 'ground_A')
                 .set_axis(['x', 'y', 'group'], axis='columns')
                 .drop_duplicates())
                
ground_B_df = (df.loc[:, ['ground_x_B', 'ground_y_B']]
                 .assign(group = 'ground_B')
                 .set_axis(['x', 'y', 'group'], axis='columns')
                 .drop_duplicates())
                
# BUILD LONG FORM DATASET           
long_df = pd.concat([main_df, ground_A_df, ground_B_df], ignore_index=True)


sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.relplot(data = long_df, x = 'x', y = 'y', hue = 'group', s = 25)
```

[image: Plot Output]

---

Alternatively, consider integrating a `col` argument and distinguish `ground` point as larger circle than other data points:

```py
main_df = (df.loc[:, ['x', 'y', 'group']]
             .assign(ground = lambda x: x['group'], size=25))

# DRY-er CODE WITH LIST COMPREHENSION
ground_dfs = [(df.loc[:, [f'ground_x_{i}', f'ground_y_{i}']]
                 .assign(group = i, ground = i, size=100)
                 .set_axis(['x', 'y', 'group', 'ground', 'size'], axis='columns')
                 .drop_duplicates())
               for i in list('AB')] 
                
# BUILD LONG FORM DATASET WITH NEW COLUMNS FOR ground AND size
long_df = pd.concat([main_df] + ground_dfs, ignore_index=True)

sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.relplot(data = long_df, x = 'x', y = 'y', col = 'ground', 
            hue = 'group', size = 'size', legend = 'full')
```

[image: Plot Output]